# How do you handle outputs from google maps distance matrix api when using with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, dictionary, google-distancematrix-api

I need assistance handling the dict file type that is returned from the google maps api.

Currently, the results are handing me a dict of the resulting data (starting addresses, ending addresses, travel times, distances etc) which I cannot process. I can extract the start and end addresses simply, but the bulk data is proving difficult to extract, and I think it is because of its structure.

The sample of the code I have is as follows;

```
import googlemaps
import csv
import pandas as pd
postcodes = pd.read_csv("SW.csv", sep=',', usecols=['postcode'], squeeze=True)
infile1 = open('SW.csv', 'r')
reader1 = csv.reader(infile1)
Location1 = postcodes[0:10]
Location2 = 'SW1A 2HQ'
my_distance = gmaps.distance_matrix(Location1, Location2, mode='bicycling', language=None, avoid=None, units='metric',
                                        departure_time='2475925955', arrival_time=None,
                                        transit_routing_preference=None)
print(my_distance)
```

Which generates the following output;

> {'origin_addresses': ['Cossar Mews, Brixton, London SW2 2TR, UK',
>   'Bushnell Rd, London SW17 8QP, UK', 'Maltings Pl, Fulham, London SW6
>   2BX, UK', 'Knightsbridge, London SW7 1BJ, UK', 'Chelsea, London SW3
>   3EE, UK', 'Hester Rd, London SW11 4AJ, UK', 'Brixton, London SW2 1HZ,
>   UK', 'Randall Cl, London SW11 3TG, UK', 'Sloane St, London SW1X 9SF,
>   UK', 'Binfield Rd, London SW4 6TA, UK'], 'rows': [{'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '28 mins', 'value': 1657}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '7.5 km', 'value': 7507}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '31 mins', 'value': 1850}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '9.2 km', 'value': 9176}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '27 mins', 'value': 1620}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '7.0 km', 'value': 7038}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '16 mins', 'value': 953}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '4.0 km', 'value': 4038}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '15 mins', 'value': 899}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '3.4 km', 'value': 3366}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '21 mins', 'value': 1260}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '5.3 km', 'value': 5265}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '28 mins', 'value': 1682}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '7.5 km', 'value': 7502}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '23 mins', 'value': 1368}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '5.9 km', 'value': 5876}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '14 mins', 'value': 839}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '3.3 km', 'value': 3341}}]}, {'elements':
>   [{'duration': {'text': '16 mins', 'value': 982}, 'status': 'OK',
>   'distance': {'text': '4.3 km', 'value': 4294}}]}],
>   'destination_addresses': ['Horse Guards Rd, London SW1A 2HQ, UK'],
>   'status': 'OK'}

I am then using the following code to extract it;

```
origin = my_distance['origin_addresses']
dest = my_distance['destination_addresses']
dist = my_distance['rows']
```

I have tried the df_from_list and many others to try and process the dist data. The end goal is to have a matrix with the origin addresses on each row, the destination addresses forming columns, with distance and time as data variables within these columns.

Something similar to this

```
        |         DEST 1        |        DEST 2         |
        |   TIME    |      DIST |      TIME |      DIST |
START 1 |      X    |      Y    |     Z     |       T   |
START 2 |      A    |      B    |     C     |       T   |
```

Please can someone help me process the my_distance output (shown above) into an architecture similar to that shown above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basicly creates a dictionary with the starts and the destination adresses.
The destination adresses have a list of tupels as values. The first element in the tuple is the duration and the second the distance
e.g. `(45, 7.0)#45=45min and 7.0 = 7km`. Then I create the dataframe with [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {d_adresses:[] for d_adresses in data['destination_addresses']}
dct['starts'] = []
for i in range(len(data['origin_addresses'])):
    duration=int(data['rows'][i]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'].split(' ')[0])
    distance=float(data['rows'][i]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'].split(' ')[0])

    for key in dct:
        if key != 'starts':
            dct[key].append((duration, distance))

    dct['starts'].append(data['origin_addresses'][i])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct)
df.set_index('starts', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This created duplicate column values for each destination.  I had to extract the duration and distance using origin (i) and destination (key) inside the second for loop

Answer (score 1):

I create an empty dataframe before running gmaps.distance_matrix, and place the dictionary keys into the dataframe. Similar to the above solution:

```
    traffic = pd.DataFrame({'time': [], 'origins': [], 'destinations': [], 'destination_addresses': [], 'origin_addresses': [], 'rows': [], 'status': []})

    for origin in origins:
        for destination in destinations:
            traffic = traffic.append({'time': [00:00], 'origins': [origin], 'destinations': [destination]}, ignore_index=True)

            if origin != destination:
                if cityname == cityname:

                    # Get travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations
                    traffic_result = gmaps.distance_matrix((origin), (destination),
                                        mode="driving", language=None, avoid=None, units="metric",
                                        departure_time=00:00, arrival_time=None, transit_mode=None,
                                        transit_routing_preference=None, traffic_model=None, region=None)

                    for key in traffic_result.keys():
                        for value in traffic_result[key]:
                            print(key, value)
                            traffic = traffic.append({key: [value]}, ignore_index=True)
```